# Should I use the subjunctive?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which of these two sentences is more correct?

> This method is helpful in order to make sure that he **know** the directions.
>
> This method is helpful in order to make sure that he **knows** the directions.

Should the subjunctive be used in this instance?

Comment: No. The first one is ungrammatical. In modern English, the infinitive construction you're calling the "subjunctive" is not used except after certain predicates; _make sure that_ isn't one of them. Think about it --
does _make sure that_ have any shred of meaning that indicates doubt, uncertainty, or random choice?

Comment: @John: There's definitely uncertainty attached, since he may or may not know the directions. I think the subjunctive might be used here in a different language. But not English.

Answer (score -1):

It would have to be the second one. Because you would use know by itself if you were talking about yourself, for instance if **I** were to say if i know the directions i would say I know. But if i was talking about someone else for instance "he" I would say he knows, and in your case your using "he" so therefore the second sentence is correct.